# Change link after click

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need some help with js.
I have few links. 
After click on link, this link must change onclick="add('*');" on href="url.com"

```
<a onclick="add('1');"> Link1</a>
<a onclick="add('2');"> Link2</a>
<a onclick="add('3');"> Link3</a>
<a onclick="add('4');"> Link4</a>
<a onclick="add('5');"> Link5</a>
```

I will be very grateful for the help

Comment: What's the purpose of `add()` function?

Comment: So change `<a onclick="add('*');">` to `<a href="url.com">`?

Comment: adds an item to the comparison

Comment: need to first add and then replacement link ) psSorry for my english

Comment: @AleksandrPetric Sorry but I still do not understand what you are trying to do. Is that a "yes" or a "no" to my question? As in do you mean: *"must change onclick="add('\*');" **to** href="url.com" "*? Do you want to remove the `onclick` event from the element?

Comment: Yes, i have function add, after the click function is performed, and after that need to change link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```js
$('a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); //stop a from trying to navigate away
  $(this).attr('onclick', "add('*')");
  $(this).attr('href', 'http://google.com');
  
});

$('button').click(function(){
  /* Test the results*/
  $('a').each(function(){
    alert( $(this).attr('onclick') );
    alert( $(this).attr('href') );
  });
});

function add(){}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="add('1');"> Link1</a>
<a onclick="add('2');"> Link2</a>
<a onclick="add('3');"> Link3</a>
<a onclick="add('4');"> Link4</a>
<a onclick="add('5');"> Link5</a>

<button>Test the results</button>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm probably wrong to say.
You must click on for example link1, and it is in this Link1 must change link.

Comment: I don't understand. When you click on Link 2, exactly what happens to what element?

Comment: you have specified in the code for each item change link, but I need this: when you click on link1 link1 change url,  when click on the link 4 then link4 change URL

Comment: When click on link 4, it changes the url in link 4? Is that correct? Because that is what the code does right now.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry everything works perfectly!
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great, thanks. Please remember to accept a correct answer to close the question *(by clicking checkmark beside best answer)*

Answer (score 1):

You should use your `add` function like below

```
function add(url){
  // in your case url = 1 etc

  window.location.href = url; // this will replace the url in the browser and will redirect.
}
```